# Qt 5.4 QIBASE driver on windows

Tags: qt, windows-7, drivers

I have a problem with building driver for my app. In file qsql_ibase.pri what contains:

```
HEADERS += $$PWD/qsql_ibase_p.h
SOURCES += $$PWD/qsql_ibase.cpp

unix {

!contains(LIBS, .*gds.*):!contains(LIBS, .*lfb.*):LIBS += -lgds
} else {
!contains(LIBS, .*gds.*):!contains(LIBS, .*fbclient.*) {
          LIBS += -lgds32
}
}
```

And the error message is:

```
cannot find -lgds32
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I using Firebird 2.5 as superserwer
System platform: windows 7 ultimate
mingw4.9.1 used to build this

How to fix this??

Comment: Do you have gds32.lib at all? Hint: either it has another name (fbclient.lib) or subdir is not on PATH.

Comment: I have that files: fbclient_ms.lib, gds32_ms.lib, ib_util_ms.lib in Firebird folder path C:/Firebird_2_5/lib . So Im guess i should use one of them but where?

Comment: @Matt I was able to build the plugin with Qt 5.8 thanks to your hint, since only `fbclient_ms` was available. Copying and renaming that library allowed me translating the plugin without having to modify the sources. If you post an answer I'll upvote it.

Comment: @TimMeyer Did it.

Answer (score 1):

> I have that files: fbclient_ms.lib, gds32_ms.lib, ib_util_ms.lib in Firebird folder path

The problem here is that library names do not match. QIBASE driver expects **gds32.lib** which was original name in Borland pack. Firebird for some reason uses **fbclient.lib** (or fbclient_ms.lib) by default.

The best approach is to make a copy (or even just a symbolic link) with name gds32.lib, as Firebird docs actually suggest so.